# Set sqrt as yaxis scale from dropdown or button-Python/Plotly

Tags: python, button, plot, plotly

From this example here : [Set linear or log axes from button or dropdown menu](https://community.plotly.com/t/set-linear-or-log-axes-from-button-or-drop-down-menu-python/34927/2) I can use a button to change the yaxis from linear to log.
However i need to change it to sqrt.

I have looked at
from [Plotly: reference layout axis](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/) I have found that there is no type ("sqrt")

> type
> Code: fig.update_yaxes(type=)
> Type: enumerated , one of ( "-" | "linear" | "log" | "date" | "category" | "multicategory" )
> Default: "-" Sets the axis type. By default, plotly attempts to determined the axis type by looking into the data of the traces that referenced the axis in question.

Here is the exmaple code:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    y=[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    y=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
))

fig.update_layout(title_text="CIR plot ",
                          updatemenus=[
            dict(
                 buttons=list([
                     dict(label="Linear",  method="update", args=[{"yaxis":{"type": "linear"}}]),
                     dict(label="Log", method="update", args=[{"yaxis":{"type": "log"}}]),
                                  ]),
            )])

 #UPDATE Y AXIS HERE
fig.update_layout( updatemenus=[
            dict(
                 buttons=list([
                     dict(label="Linear-ID",  
                          method="relayout", 
                          args=[{"yaxis.type": "linear"}]),
                     dict(label="Log-ID", 
                          method="relayout", 
                          args=[{"yaxis.type": "log"}]),
                                  ]),
            )])
fig.show()
```

Is there a way to use a button to update the scale to sqrt ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge there's currently no way to specify `sqrt` as scale for the axis that would trigger a visual change to the axis labels like the case is for `fig.update_xaxes(type="log")`:

[image]

But you don't really have to in order to change the data associated with the yaxis to display the square roots of a given series. The complete snippet below produce a figure that will easily let you switch between displaying the raw data and a series with square roots.

#### Plot 1: Raw data

[image]

#### Plot 2: np.sqrt

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

# figure setup
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(mode="markers", x=df["gdpPercap"], y=df["lifeExp"])
fig.add_scatter(mode="markers", x=df["gdpPercap"], y=np.sqrt(df["lifeExp"]), visible = False)

# buttons for updatemenu
buttons = [dict(method='restyle',
                label='linear',
                visible=True,
                args=[{'label': 'linear',
                       'visible':[True, False],
                      }
                     ]),
           dict(method='restyle',
                label='sqrt',
                visible=True,
                args=[{'label': 'linear',
                       'visible':[False, True],
                      }
                     ])]
           
# specify updatemenu        
um = [{'buttons':buttons,
      'direction': 'down'}
      ]

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=um)
# fig.update_yaxes(type="log")
fig.show()
```

Comment: is this method  slower than changing axis type ?

Comment: @David8 Not sure. Are you experiencing issues with speed?

Comment: it's a bit slow to update when i open it as an HTML image. I have edited my quesiton with a working exmaple i have modified from your code to be more similar to mine (multiple plots,  with a linked legend). Do you think it is better to use y.axis.type for the lin/log updates while havign your method just for sqrt to be faster ?

Comment: @David8 I'd be happy to look at this too. But please consider raising any new issues as an individual question. Or else this post will quickly turn into a fine mess.

Comment: @David8 You could just make it as to-the-point as possible and refer to this post as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the desired output, in the case of switching axis domains, is to transform the shape of the curve but keep the original y values (for instance with log axis).  Since plotly does not have square root axis option you need to transform the data (as in @vestland's approach) but also transform the axis values.  This can be done with a combination of the `tickvals` and `ticktext` options for the desired axis (see [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-tickvals) and [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-ticktext))

- `tickvals=ysqrt` this sets the values at which ticks on this axis appear to the square root of `ybase`
- `ticktext=ybase` this sets the text displayed at the ticks position, here keeping the `ybase` values

Consider this example without the transformation:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

ybase=np.array([0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64])
ysqrt=np.sqrt(ybase)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),y=ybase))

fig.show()
```

[image]

And then with:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),y=ysqrt))
fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=ysqrt, ticktext=ybase)
fig.show()
```

[image]

We now have a linear representation of this curve but keeping the original y values.