# Plotly: Plotting one trace with two x-axes that are not linearly related

Tags: python, plotly

### The problem

I am trying to plot data that can be presented as either **Absorbance vs Wavelength (nm)** or **Absorbance vs Wavenumber (cm⁻¹)**. Note the conversion is **cm⁻¹ = 10⁷/nm**.

I wish to plot a single trace with one y-axis ('Absorbance') and two x-axes ( 'Wavelength (nm)' and 'Wavenumber  (cm⁻¹)' )

Presently, my plan is to graph the both traces but keep one invisible. However, I do not understand how to implement a secondary x-axis. Additionally, is there a way to scale the Wavenumber axis properly such that both the visible and invisible plots overlay each other?

### Sample Data and Starting Code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = pd.DataFrame[{'Wavelength' = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000}
                     'Absorbance' = {1.00, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.04, 1.03, 1.02, 1.01}
                     }]

def nm_convert(nm):
    wavenumber = 10000000/nm
    return wavenumber

data['Wavenumber'] = nm_convert(data['Wavelength'])

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=dataset['Wavelength'], y=dataset['Absorbance'], mode='lines', line=dict(width=1.5), name='nm_trace')
trace2 = go.Scatter(x=dataset['Wavenumber'], y=dataset['Absorbance'], name='cm-1 trace', visible=False)
```

### Example Image

I've made an example of the result I might be looking for. However, I am open to alternative suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Regarding the snippet you've provided. Best case scenario is that you're missing `import plotly.scatter_objects as go`. And then you have `data = pd.DataFrame[...]` With ***`[ ...]`***...? And then lists with ***`{...}`?*** I'm assuming your goal is to build a dataframe using a dictionary, but have you even tried *running* this snippet on your end?

Comment: @vestland Ah yes, you're right. I was copy/pasting from my actual script for my real data and was trying to cut out extraneous information. I guess I cut out a few too many lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several questions here, and I believe @vestland has answered the primary question.  But to expand on his answer and to address your second question you can use a combination of `tickvals` and `ticktext` to achieve the "rescaling" of the second axis, another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66295885/11305111).

Below is an example adapted from vestland's work, with the following comments

- there's two series here, the second is not shown with `opacity=0`
- for `xaxis2` the `tickvals` are `Wavelength` but the `ticktext` is set to the `Wavenumber` (also rounded with `round`)
- using `customdata` and `hovertemplate` on the first series to provide a unified hover

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = pd.DataFrame({'Wavelength' : [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000],
                     'Absorbance' : [1.00,1.01,1.02,1.03,1.04,1.05,1.04,1.03,1.02,1.01]})
data['Wavenumber'] = 10000000/data['Wavelength']

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=data['Wavelength'], 
                          y=data['Absorbance'],
                          customdata=data['Wavenumber'],
                          showlegend=False,
                          hovertemplate=
                            "Wavelength: %{x}<br>" +
                            "Wavenumber: %{customdata:.0f}<br>" +
                            "Absorbance: %{y}" +
                            "<extra></extra>",))
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=data['Wavelength'], 
                          y=data['Absorbance'], 
                          showlegend=False, 
                          opacity=0, 
                          hoverinfo='skip',
                          xaxis="x2"))

fig.update_layout(xaxis= {'title':'Wavelength','showgrid':False,})
fig.update_layout(yaxis= {'title':'Absorbance','showgrid':False,})
fig.update_layout(xaxis2= {'title':'Wavenumber', 'showgrid':False,
                           'anchor': 'y', 
                           'overlaying': 'x', 
                           'side': 'top',
                           'tickvals':data['Wavelength'],
                           'ticktext':data['Wavenumber'].round(decimals=-2)})
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: please note, this answer is addressing the _secondary_ question of "is there a way to scale the Wavenumber axis..."  if possible please reconsider @vestland's answer as the "best" answer.

Comment: @jayveesa Nah, I think you're more on point here. Well deserved accepted status!

Comment: jayveesea @vestland In any case, thank you both very much for your help! And extra thanks to vestland for teaching me how to post properly on this forum

Answer (score 2):

The setup you've provided is a bit messed up. If you make the necessary corrections, you can add the following details for your layout and secondary x-axis:

```
fig.update_layout(xaxis2= {'anchor': 'y', 'overlaying': 'x', 'side': 'top'})
fig.data[1].update(xaxis='x2')
fig
```

And get:

[image]

#### Complete code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = pd.DataFrame({'Wavelength' : [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000],
                     'Absorbance' : [1.00, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.04, 1.03, 1.02, 1.01]
                     })

def nm_convert(nm):
    wavenumber = 10000000/nm
    return wavenumber

data['Wavenumber'] = nm_convert(data['Wavelength'])

fig = go.Figure()

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=data['Wavelength'], y=data['Absorbance'], mode='lines', line=dict(width=1.5), name='nm_trace')
trace2 = go.Scatter(x=data['Wavenumber'], y=data['Absorbance'], name='cm-1 trace', visible=False)

fig.add_traces(trace1)
fig.add_traces(trace2)

fig.update_layout(xaxis2= {'anchor': 'y', 'overlaying': 'x', 'side': 'top'})
fig.data[1].update(xaxis='x2')
fig
fig.layout.xaxis.title = '<b><i>Wavelength</i></b>'
fig.layout.xaxis2.title = '<b><i>Wavenumber</i></b>'
fig.layout.yaxis.title = '<b><i>Absorbance</i></b>'

fig.layout.xaxis2
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps me get the secondary axis up top. However, I want the secondary axis (Wavenumber) to scale reciprocally with the primary x axis (Wavelength) rather than linearly. This is because Wavelength and Wavenumber are inversely related. Is this possible to do with Plotly?

Comment: @gopher Will reversing the secondary xaxis suffice?

Comment: Not exactly. The reason is because it will still be linear (just inversely linear: x → –x). But with a reciprocal axis, for every x value on the primary axis, you would have, for example, the 1/x value at the corresponding point (x → 1/x). Or more specifically in my case: x → 10⁷/x
I updated the image at the bottom of the posted question. Maybe that clarifies it better

Comment: imho this answer's the primary question of "how to implement a secondary x-axis"