# Update visibility of Traces with fig.update_layout Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Following on from this quesiton: [Set sqrt as yaxis scale from dropdown or button-Python/Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66226542/set-sqrt-as-yaxis-scale-from-dropdown-or-button-python-plotly)

I want to :

1. Define a plot with all traces: visible = False

```py
fig.add_scatter(mode="markers", x=df["gdpPercap"], y=df["lifeExp"], visible = False) #set both vis to False 
fig.add_scatter(mode="markers", x=df["gdpPercap"], y=np.sqrt(df["lifeExp"]), visible = False)
```

2. Create an update button that can make trace1 or trace2 become visbile

```py
# buttons for updatemenu
buttons = [dict(method='restyle',
                label='linear',
                visible=True,
                args=[{'label': 'linear',
                       'visible':[True, False],
                      }
                     ]),.....
         
 um = [{'buttons':buttons,
      'direction': 'down'}
      ]

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=um)
```

3. Set inital condition to be trace1 = visible, trace2 =invisible

```py
fig.update_layout(dict(args = {"visible": [True, False]}))
```

The first 2 points have been solved.
I cannot find a way to preset the initial display conditions. In this example i could easily change the visibility while creating the traces, but in my real problem it would be harder.

This is the full example:

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

# figure setup
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_scatter(mode="markers", x=df["gdpPercap"], y=df["lifeExp"], visible = False) #set both vis to False 
fig.add_scatter(mode="markers", x=df["gdpPercap"], y=np.sqrt(df["lifeExp"]), visible = False)

# buttons for updatemenu
buttons = [dict(method='restyle',
                label='linear',
                visible=True,
                args=[{'label': 'linear',
                       'visible':[True, False],
                      }
                     ]),
           dict(method='restyle',
                label='sqrt',
                visible=True,
                args=[{'label': 'linear',
                       'visible':[False, True],
                      }
                     ])]
           
# specify updatemenu        
um = [{'buttons':buttons,
      'direction': 'down'}
      ]

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=um)


 #Update plot before showing to make 1st trace visible COMMENTED OUT CODE NOT WORKING 
# fig.update_layout(dict(args = {"visible": [True, False]}))

fig.show()
```

Comment: it's not clear why you need step3... why not preset in step1 with `fig.add_scatter(mode="markers", x=df["gdpPercap"], y=df["lifeExp"], visible = True)`?

Comment: @jayveesa, in my real example i use a more complicated loop to add the traces, so i would prefer to update later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can conditionally update the trace as shown [here](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#conditionally-updating-traces).

First when you add each trace give it a `name` (using 'linear' and 'sqrt' in this case):

```
fig.add_scatter(mode="markers", x=df["gdpPercap"], y=df["lifeExp"], 
                visible = False, name='linear')
fig.add_scatter(mode="markers", x=df["gdpPercap"], y=np.sqrt(df["lifeExp"]), 
                visible = False, name='sqrt')
```

Then later on use a conditional update that sets `visible=True` if the name is "linear":

```
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace: trace.update(visible=True) if trace.name == "linear" else (),
)
```

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

fig = go.Figure()
# adding names for reference
fig.add_scatter(mode="markers", x=df["gdpPercap"], y=df["lifeExp"], 
                visible = False, name='linear')
fig.add_scatter(mode="markers", x=df["gdpPercap"], y=np.sqrt(df["lifeExp"]), 
                visible = False, name='sqrt')

# buttons for updatemenu
buttons = [dict(method='restyle',
                label='linear',
                visible=True,
                args=[{'label': 'linear',
                       'visible':[True, False],}]),
           dict(method='restyle',
                label='sqrt',
                visible=True,
                args=[{'label': 'linear',
                       'visible':[False, True],}])]
           
# specify updatemenu        
um = [{'buttons':buttons, 'direction': 'down'}]
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=um)

# Conditionally Updating Traces 
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace: trace.update(visible=True) if trace.name == "linear" else (),
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question, however the example i gave was too simplistic, i'm going to open a new question with a better constructed example: i don't want to update from the name, but more from the button label. I'll tag you into the new quesiton