# Update visibility of traces with fig.update using the button property?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Following on from [Update visibility of Traces with fig.update_layout Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66414456/update-visibility-of-traces-with-fig-update-layout-plotly/66415620#66415620), I want to pre-set the visibility of a trace with update_layout, to match the status of the first button.

Since the example i gave in the previous question was too simplistic, the correct asnwer of @jayveesea wasn't applicaable to my case: i cannot update from trace.name but rather need to update from button name. I have creaated a new example:

I have a dataframe with "pixel", "VGs", "x", "y".

- The update button changes between "pixels"
- The legendroup and tracename is given by "VG"
- I am plotting y vs x, with color given by VG and the button changing between pixels.

I am plotting all the traces with visible = False. I then want to update the plot so that all traces where pixel=1 are visible. (basically as if button 1 was pressed)

This is a new full working exmaple:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


df = pd.DataFrame ({"pixel":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                    "VGs":   [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                    "x":    [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                    "y":    [2,4,6,8,4,8,12,16,3,9,27,81,6,18,54,162,4,12,75,200,8,24,150,400]
                    
                    })

 #make Vis/invis buttons for pixels 
buttons=[]
pixels = df.pixel.unique()
for pixel in pixels : 
  vis = list(np.isin(pixels,pixel ))
  dict_ = dict(method='restyle',
          label="pixel " +str(pixel),
          visible=True,
          args=[{'label': "pixel " +str(pixel),
                       'visible':vis,
                      }
                     ])
 
 
  buttons.append(dict_)


um = [{'buttons':buttons,
      'direction': 'down'}
      ]

 #color map
VG_distinct_colors ={}
distinc_color = ['#e6194b', '#3cb44b', '#ffe119', '#4363d8', '#f58231', '#911eb4', '#46f0f0']
for indx, VG in enumerate(list(df['VGs'].unique())):
  VG_distinct_colors[VG] =distinc_color[indx] 

 #start figure
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
 #In legend show VG, button update change Pixel
for (VG, pixel), grp in df.groupby (["VGs", "pixel"]):
  fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=grp["x"], y=grp["y"], legendgroup=str(VG), visible = False,mode='lines', name = str(VG), line_color=VG_distinct_colors[VG],
                           ),   col=1, row=1)



fig.update_layout(updatemenus=um)

### SOMETHING HERE LIKE 
**fig.update_layout(Traces that are related to Button 1 are visible)**

fig.show()
```

Comment: If pixel1 is `'visible': [True, True, True]`, I think your goal will be achieved.

Comment: How do i set pixel 1 to visibile?

Comment: If you want to create it manually or process it in a loop, you have to prepare such a list to handle it. `[[True, True, True],[False, True, False],[False, False, True]]`

Comment: with something like : 
fig.update_layout({"visible": [[True,True,True], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]})
?

Comment: That's right. It might be the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: It isn't quite working for now, is it the correct syntax or how do i pass visible in layout?

Comment: Kindly refer to [this](https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/#update-dropdown).

Comment: I modified the `print(buttons)` output created by the loop process and assigned it to the buttons variable and checked it in my environment.

Comment: take a look at this [example with sliders](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/#simple-slider-control), some of the methods may be relevant here (and a slider may also be an option).

Comment: If you still haven't solved the problem, I can post my code for you.

Comment: I have solved it with a work around, using modifying the for looop so that only pixel 1 is visible. But your solution posted would be most welcome

Comment: I'm glad it's been resolved. Self-answers for users are also welcome.